# Google Drive File Stream kicks regular Google Drive out of Windows Quick Access

Tags: google-drive, windows

I run Google Drive File Stream (GDFS) and Google Backup and Sync (GBS) simultaneously on Windows 10. I'd like to have both in the Quick Access list at the left of the Windows Explorer window. But it always seems to revert to having GDFS and not GBS in the list.

To replicate:

1. Have GDFS and GBS (Google Backup and Sync) installed and running.
2. Right click on the Google Drive (GBS) folder anywhere in Windows explorer, and Pin to Quick access.
3. Note that Google Drive does appear in the Quick Access list.
4. (Optionally, unpin GDFS from Quick Access. This does not make a difference.)
5. Restart Windows.
6. Note that GDFS is (back) in Quick Access and Google Drive is not.

Has anyone gotten this to work? Is there a hack by which I can force the change?